# How can I change the title icon?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, icons

How can I change the title icon using html in chrome browser? I need to change the title bar icon with a saved image on my computer, I watched many tutorial to find it so easy to do but still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called a "favicon." The standard way to do it is to create a .png file of the icon and add a tag like this to the `<head>` of your page(s)

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

Here's a good reference - https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon

Comment: Thanks, it worked finally :)

Answer (score 0):

If think you're talking about the favicon, so to set it in HTML, put this code in your `<head>` : 
 `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="pathToYourIcon.png" />`

Comment: Thanks, it worked finally :)

Comment: You can mark my answer as "best answer" (the green tick) if it helped you, it will help the others :)